# Level 7 display relationship data in blade using one to many

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

whats wrong why in blade don't want to show the **LEVEL name**

**controller:**

```
 $streams=Stream::with('level')->get();
 return view('streams.index',compact('streams'));
```

**Stream Model:**

```
 public function level()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Level', 'level_id');
    }
```

**Level Model:**

```
public function stream()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Stream', 'level_id');
    }
```

**Blade Index:**

```
@foreach($streams as $stream)
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">#</th>
                        <td>{{$stream->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$stream->code}}</td>
                        <td>
                        {{$stream->level->name}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                      <tr/>
@endforeach
```

**Also tried:**

```
@foreach($streams as $stream)
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">#</th>
                        <td>{{$stream->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$stream->code}}</td>
                        @foreach($stream as $level)
                        <td>
                        {{$level->name}}
                        </td>
                        @endforeach
                        <td>
                      <tr/>
                   @endforeach
```

Error:
**Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\sms\resources\views\streams\index.blade.php)**

DD result:

```
 [{"id":3,"name":"Class A","code":"GRC0001A","uuid":"X9HG9zc7ceTlhdfF1fN1wAer1cHP1MhfuM7GHBSqNogYSo3bsGmpTl06iJQyyKp3QMrkHe1VyiTxeKFa49wC7W5BY3E3kFZkpF1D","level_id":1,"created_at":"2020-06-14T10:58:28.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-06-14T11:39:54.000000Z","level":{"id":1,"name":"YEAR 7","code":"CODE1","uuid":"X9HG9zc7ceTlhdfF1fN1wAer1cHP1MhfuM7GHBSqNogYSo3bsGmpTl06iJQyyKp3QMrkHe1VyiTxeKFa49wC7W5BY3E3kFZkpF1D","created_at":"-000001-11-30T00:00:00.000000Z","updated_at":"-000001-11-30T00:00:00.000000Z"}},{"id":4,"name":"Class B","code":"GRC0001A","uuid":"gq2kZZikN76XEa4pQWsyAZBMxjKeHBJt0a840ZMSiuHGztuhYT0G6q5WcGgp8z6BD6nx0WSrrOTvEb4iQ0ewyB9Fa1M54CAv8HS2","level_id":null,"created_at":"2020-06-14T10:58:36.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-06-14T11:39:59.000000Z","level":null}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first Blade template is almost correct.

The issue is that one or more of your records has no `Level` assigned (`level_id=null`), but you're still trying to pull the name property from `$stream->level`, which is `null`.

Simply add a check for $stream->level before trying to access/print its properties. For example:

```
@if($stream->level)
   {{ $stream->level->name }} 
@endif
```

or

```
{{ $stream->level ? $stream->level->name : 'No Level Attached' }}
```

or

```
{{ optional($stream->level)->name }}
```

etc.

Comment: thank you u made things clear, Yes one of the data is null that's why it's giving me error. now i know how to approach thank you for ur help..